# Role Based Security in JavaScript in RIA

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, security, ria

I'm trying to learn the development of Web Applications in JavaScript, and for this I am developing a simple Time Tracking application. I am developing this with ExtJS for dynamically creating the UI.

This would allow Employees to submit the time they have spent working on different projects, and allow the Managers, to add Projects to Users and so on.

Once the user signs in, I determine their role, and provide the appropriate UI (through JavaScript).

I was wondering what is the best and most secure way of doing this? (I am of course checking the authorization on the server side, so that no one can make changes by just calling my PHP Services via http get/post)

I asking from a perspective of disallowing a non authorized person, to even see the non-authorized UI, by fiddling with the JavaScript (from the FireBug console for example).

I was thinking of creating a Service which returns the appropriate script for creating the appropriate UI, through JSONP.  It feels quite *WTF-ey* to me, so I was wondering if there was better way.

Comment: The question might be too general to get a reasonable answer. You can never be sure noone builds the admin user UI for himself. The most common practise is that the backend has everything secured and the frontend is static and if someone wants to download the bits of UI he will not be able to use, it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

To build on naugtur's comment.  You must always assume that there will be a very smart person that can build the UI for himself/herself, or fake any of the calls to the server that any part of the UI could do.

Based on that, the premise of the way you suggested towards the end of your question seems debunk to begin with.  The easiest route once we settle that (I'm assuming your making a single-page application) would be to always dump all the javascript code right up front at the login screen and only allow the user to see what they need to based on their role (i.e. a card panel that has different cards for each role would be an example).

I would also like to add that on the backend of the application, you should always have security checks in place to make sure the user has the correct role for whatever action he is doing.  If your application is internet facing, this is a necessity, there will always be that user who will look through your code and see what he can do maliciously or just for fun...  or that guy on who wants to see what happens when he uses the debugger to create his own fake ajax calls with varying parameters.

Comment: I will also add that I have done exactly your requirements in a large project last year.